# Why getRolloverTab is not working as expected in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have created my own custom `jTabbedPane` Class exteding `BasicTabbedPaneUI`. Everything is working great as expected except for one thing and that is I cannot get my **getRolloverTab()** method of `BasicTabbedPaneUI` work as expected.

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;


public class HAAMS 
{
  //My Custom class for jTabbedPane
  public static class CustomMainMenuTabs extends BasicTabbedPaneUI
  {
    protected void paintTabBackground(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Color color;

        if (isSelected) { color = new Color(74, 175, 211); } 
        else if (getRolloverTab() == tabIndex) {  color = new Color(45, 145, 180); } 
        else {color = new Color(68, 67, 67);}

        g2.setPaint(color);
        g2.fill(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h, 30, 30));

        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x + 100,y,w,h));
    }
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     JFrame MainScreen = new JFrame("Custom JTabbedPane");
     MainScreen.setExtendedState(MainScreen.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

     //Setting UI for my jTabbedPane implementing my custom class CustomMainMenuTabs
     JTabbedPane jtpane = new JTabbedPane(2);
     jtpane.setUI(new CustomMainMenuTabs());
     jtpane.add("1st Tabe", new JPanel());
     jtpane.add("2nd Tabe", new JPanel());
     jtpane.add("3rd Tabe", new JPanel());

     MainScreen.getContentPane().add(jtpane);
     MainScreen.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

What is that which I am going wrong and this does not change background color of tab when mouse hovers the tab? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can see that in my IF condition, getRolloverTab() condition is given which should change the color of the tab when mouse hovers over the tab but the problem is that it doesn't change color when mouse hovers over the tab. While if(isSelected) condition and else condition are working good just getRolloverTab() condition is not working. Where am I making mistake.

Comment: Where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating your problem? You were also asked for a `SSCCE` in your last question. If you want people to give you examples, then post a proper SSCCE so we can make changes. Don't expect us to write the entire code!!!

Comment: @camickr I have already provided my whole code demonstrating the problem that even there I have coded for getRolloverTab() in my if condition but yet when the mouse is hovered over the tab and hover color doesn't change. What else you call SSCCE? And I am not expecting someone to write code for me I just asked for the solution that where is my mistake in my code that my code is not working when mouse hovers over the tab.

Comment: `What else you call SSCCE?` - How can I execute that code? How is that class used with the tabbed pane? How to you create and display the tabbed pane in a JFrame? Also yo still haven't shown your `SSCCE` for your other question when you add a MouseListener to the tabbed pane and use the `tabForCooridinate(...)` method. It is annoying when I spend the time to help and then you just ignore the advice.

Comment: @camickr I didn't want to hurt you by any means. I was in a hurry and that's put the main code here. Well Thanks for taking time. Let me put what your really call SSCCE. Sorry if that hurt you.

Comment: @camickr I have put my all of the code with everything you asked. Hope this makes sense now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me update my previous question as well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. You should copy/paste your testing code so you don't waste our time. I have other stuff to do now, that is why you should make an effort to get it right the first time. By the way did you add any debug code to your class to see what the value of the rollover tab is?